# Storing Get Count Tool Results in Data table using ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, feature-class, count

I'm trying to take counts of feature class.

In ModelBuilder there is option **Get Count tool** it is useful, but the result will appear in **result window** it shows counts.

***How do I store counts in a data table?***

Comment: Would Summary Statistics be what you're after? https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001z000000

Comment: it is not enough, because if we have one feature class it will, but i need to get counts of minimum 20 feature classes.

Comment: Then run 20 summary statistics (some iterator might be needed here) and then merge https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000055000000 the results.

Comment: append process is taking to much time, i tried that also get count                                                                 is simple.is there any possibilities to store Get Count Tool Values and i have point ,line and polygon features so it not possible.

Comment: If you step outside of model builder and into python there is, either as a script or mammoth field calculator expression. I would suggest you merge (not append) the summary tables not the input feature classes... 20 or so tables should merge in seconds.

Comment: anyway thanks **Michael Stimson**

Comment: The Append operation on 20 tables should be a fairly rapid step in modelbuilder. If your are saying it is taking too long that would strongly suggest you have  poorly designed model, which can often happen if you are using iterators.These need to be in sub-models with a collects tool feeding out a list of table paths to an Append tool. People regularly make the mistake of having all this in the master model. As you show us nothing about your model I can only speculate...